# how can i save an image for any user

Tags: python, django

In my website user can upload a image to edit it so i should save his image in model and to access again to image i should save username of user for any image.  I want when user go to home page his image be deleted. But i have problem. This error: 
**OperationalError at /
no such column: imgProcess_image.username**

```
# model
    class Image(models.Model):
        username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_images')


# form
    class Upload(forms.ModelForm):
        username = Image.username

        class Meta:
            model = Image
            fields = ['image']

        def set_user(self, un):
            self.username = un


# views
    def delete_image_of_user(request):
        Image.objects.get(username=request.user.username).delete()

    def home(request):
        delete_image_of_user(request)
        hash = {}
        comments = CommentModel.objects.all()
        hash["comments"] = comments
        return render(request, "imgProcess/home.html", hash)
```

Comment: Can you move the Image model to your models.py, also in the admin.py register this model using admin.site.register(Image) and then run python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate. You can refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/overview/ for an overview of the structure we create our projects on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database has unapplied migrations if you see in your database you wont find username column in Image table. You should build and apply migrations. Run `python manage.py makemigrations` then `python manage.py migrate` to apply them.

Comment: I run makemigrations and migrate but that did not change!!

Comment: did migrations detect the change?

Comment: can you post latest migrations  file?

Comment: No changes detected

Comment: check in migrations folder the last migrations generated.. you can do `python manage.py makemigrations imgProcess (your app name)` to look for changes

Comment: did you try `python manage.py makemigrations imgProcess (your app name)`

Comment: Yes and it is not empty any more. But i see error yet.

Comment: what is error after `python manage.py migrate imgProcess (your app name)` ?

Comment: It does not give the erroe. But when I open the home page, or open the Image model on the admin page, I'll go back to the previous erroe:OperationalError at /admin/imgProcess/image/
no such column: imgProcess_image.username

Comment: remove the field username for a while do makemigrations and migrate add the field again and makemigrations then migrate

Comment: It works :) . can you help me how to initial username of model when this field is not in form?

Comment: I think you missed one of migrations.. it worked because it detected change in model thats how migrations work  so I will recommend to explicitly detect migrations by `python manage.py makemigrations appname`